# Using WinDbg on Windows 2008 running .NET 4.7.1

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-server-2008, windbg

I would like to debug .NET 4.7.1 application running on Windows 2008. Issue I'm facing is that Windows Server SKD/WDK come with the support for .NET 4.0
How can I get WinDbg to run on Windows 2008 and debug 4.7.1 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some instructions.
You can try using the commands below to load extensions:

```
.cordll -ve -u -l
```

do not forget to create the environment variable:

```
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH = SRV*C:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;
```

Comment: WinDbg does not need `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`. It has a) the concept of workspaces which can hold different symbol paths for different purposes and b) `.symfix C:\symcache` can change the symbol path without the need for an environment variable.

Comment: Using Microsoft's symbol repository is useful because it makes the stack view clearer and the save directory can be changed without problems.

Comment: I didn't doubt that. `.symfix` does exactly that

Comment: The directory is implicit in the .simfix command: If LocalSymbolCache is omitted, the sym subdirectory of the debugger installation directory will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK may include a .NET framework version and a WinDbg version. However, this does not mean that the WinDbg version and the .NET version are linked together. In fact, WinDbg comes without any support for .NET.

The support for .NET comes with the .NET framework itself. Whatever .NET framework is installed, it will have a SOS.DLL:

[image: Screenshots of SOS DLLs]

SOS is a debugging extension for WinDbg. It provides .NET specific commands.

You typically load the extension with

```
.loadby sos clr
```

which means: find out where the CLR.DLL is located and from the same folder, load the SOS.DLL as an extension.

So, just use whatever WinDbg version you have and load the extension for whatever .NET version the process uses.